# How can I get code inside an else statement out while still making the if part work?

Tags: javascript

I have the following:

```
if (!program.args.length) {
    program.help()
} else {
    var filename = program.args[0]

    fs.readFile(filename, 'utf8', function(err, data) {
        if (err) throw err

        var tree = markdown.parse(data);
        (function update_tree(jsonml) {
            for (i = 1; i < jsonml.length; i++) {
                if (jsonml[i][0] === 'hr') {
                    var par = jsonml[i + 1]
                    console.log(par)
                    par.splice(1, 0, {
                        'class': 'noind'
                    })
                }
                //if (jsonml[i][0] === 'para') {
                //var par = jsonml[i]
                //par.splice(1, 0, {'class': 'noind'})
                //}
            }
        })(tree)

        var html = markdown.renderJsonML(markdown.toHTMLTree(tree))
        console.log(html)
    })
}
```

Is there a way to get the code inside `else` out while keeping the `if` part working?

(The reason I want to do this is to remove one level of indentation.)

Comment: else if - is not doing this ?

Comment: You could wrap the code in a function and return from the *then* branch. However, that would also add a level of indentation, so you'll be back to square one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can.

```
if (condition) {
    doSomething();
    return; // Don't continue onwards
}
// Anything here is equivalent to else
```

Please note that in this scenario, if condition matches, the function will return immediately.